# Scroll View in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, scrollview

First ,I am sorry for my bad English,  how to display my Expandable list View and Grid View ,,when I am trying to do that I am getting error
Exception raised during rendering:

```
Scroll View can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

**Code :**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.samp.sampleproh.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >



 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="205dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.41"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ExpandableListView>


    <GridView
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your expandable listview and gridview to one common relative layout and that will resolve your issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="205dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.41"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ExpandableListView>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lvExp"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i had another doubt where i need to place my view pager code @parth bhayani

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

Answer (score 1):

The reason you getting error is because `<Scrollview/>` tag can host only one child. Means you can not define more than one child directly in `<Scrollview/>` like you did it here.

You have defined `<Gridview/>` and `<ExpandableListView/>` inside `<Scrollview/>`. Its not a normal behavior for `<Scrollview/>`.

Refer this link..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

**It says...**

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

**Solution :**

> You have to combine both view inside any other parent view e.g. `<LinearLayout/>` or `<RelativeLayout/>`.

**Sample Code :**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ExpandableListView/>
            <GridView/>

        <LinearLayout/>

</ScrollView>
```